# Baggage allowance for international travellers in India

Tags: india, indigo

I am travelling to India next month. I am carrying 2 check-in bags coming from the USA. I wanted to know if the domestic flights like Indigo allow free bags for international travellers, or is there an alternate way to go from Bangalore to a tier-3 city?

Comment: Are you booking this as part of an international itinerary or as separate tickets?

Comment: Nopes, A single PNR has no issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indigo's [own website](https://www.goindigo.in/baggage/baggage-allowance.html) states

> - For customers on IndiGo connecting flights from domestic to international sectors or vice-versa: IndiGo’s free baggage allowance for international sectors will apply only to bookings made on a single PNR.
> - IndiGo Domestic Sector connecting to another airline to/from an international destination: 15 Kg per passenger. Baggage in excess of 15 kgs will be subject to additional charges of INR 550 per kg. Additional charge of INR 550 per kg would be levied in case the weight exceeds 15 kgs. Excess Baggage charges are non-refundable in case of no shows and gate no shows.

Here "PNR" stands for [Passenger Name Record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passenger_name_record) which can (very loosely) be equated with a ticket in our modern electronic age where nothing's on paper. As such, if you've already booked a codeshare flight all the way to your final destination you may be ok, otherwise you're likely to be expected to pay. This is pretty much the standard worldwide these days.

Comment: It’s quite unclear what they mean by “_IndiGo’s free baggage allowance for international sectors_” as they have so many different ones. But the usual IaTA rule is that the allowance in the most significant sector applies to the whole trip, so that’s probably the case here also (again, only in the case of a single ticket).